# Avoid sorting columns when unstacking a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When unstacking a `pd.DataFrame` from a long format to a wide format, pandas automatically sorts the columns in an ascending order. How can I avoid sorting at all? I get my expected the result, when I reorder the columns manually. However, this can't be the best solution, can it?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"cols": ["B", "A", "C", "D"],
     "rows": [2, 1, 3, 4],
     "value": [3, 1, 2,4]})

df = df.set_index(["cols", "rows"], drop=True)
print(df)

           value
cols rows       
B    2         3
A    1         1
C    3         2
D    4         4

actual_result = df.unstack(level="cols").droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
print(actual_result)

cols    A    B    C    D
rows                    
1     1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2     NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0

expected_result = actual_result[["B", "A", "C", "D"]]
print(expected_result)

cols    B    A    C    D
rows                    
1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: It is the best solution that I know of indeed. It makes more sense to sort the index/columns to me than not.

Comment: Also `df['value'].unsatck('cols')` save you a `droplevel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea like change values in last step is use ordered categoricals in original column:

```
df["cols"] = pd.Categorical(df["cols"], ordered=True, categories=df["cols"].unique())
df = df.set_index(["cols", "rows"], drop=True)


actual_result = df.unstack(level="cols").droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
print(actual_result)
cols    B    A    C    D
rows                    
1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Another idea is used unique values of original column in `reindex`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(["cols", "rows"], drop=True)
print(df1)


actual_result = (df1.unstack(level="cols")
                    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
                    .reindex(df["cols"].unique(), axis=1))
print(actual_result)
cols    B    A    C    D
rows                    
1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Or unique values of first level in `df1`:

```
df1 = df.set_index(["cols", "rows"], drop=True)
print(df1)


actual_result = (df1.unstack(level="cols")
                    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
                    .reindex(df1.index.get_level_values(0).unique(), axis=1))
print(actual_result)

cols    B    A    C    D
rows                    
1     NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN
2     3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3     NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
4     NaN  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: This would be painful if `cols` were already the index.

Comment: @QuangHoang - absolutely agree ;)

Comment: I like your last suggestion the most. However, it's not as intuitive as it should be, in my view. The best thing would be an input argument for the ``unstack`` function itself. I'm thinking about something like ``sort=False``.